# Highlighting of $...$ syntax in WinEdt 9

Tags: highlighting, winedt, syntax

In WinEdt 8.0 the text within dollar signs `$...$` in the .tex file was highlighted by using a different background color than the rest of the text. I installed WinEdt 9.0 and this effect is no longer there. I would like the background of the text within `$...$` to be highlighted.

After some searching I found that I can manually change the highlighting in the `Switches.ini` file. I think I need to look at the following lines of code

```
SWITCH="$?$"
   ENABLED=1
   MODE_FILTER="TeX|DTX;INS;STY;AUX"
   START="$"
   STOP="$"
   HIGHLIGHT_START=1
   STEP_OVER_STOP=1
   HIGHLIGHT_STOP=1
   SCOPE=3
   DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
   STRICT_PRIORITY=0
   PRIORITY=5
   INDENTED=0
   BOLN_ONLY=0
   CASE_SENSITIVE=1
   START1_TRIGGER=""
   START2_TRIGGER=""
   STOP1_TRIGGER=""
   STOP2_TRIGGER=""
          TEXT_COLOR="xclMath"
          DEFAULT_FONT=1
          ITALIC=1
```

When examining other switches, I come across these lines in the `SWITCH = "$$?$$"` part

```
   CUSTOM_BACKGROUND=1
   GRADIENT_BACKGROUND=256
   TRANSPARENT=128
   GRADIENT_COLOR="xclEnvBkLeftGradient"
   BACKGROUND_COLOR="xclEnvBk"
```

However, adding these lines at the end of the code for the switch `"$?$"` changes nothing in the .tex file. What am I doing incorrectly?

Moreover, even changing the command `ITALIC=1` to `ITALIC=0` does not seem to change anything. Am I even looking in the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add only `BACKGROUND_COLOR="xclEnvBk"` in the section of switches.ini. The rest of the setting from `$$` are for multiline backgrounds. And don't forget to load the script.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. I was unaware that I needed to load the script.