# Winedt: Colouring Commands

Tags: winedt

How to put the commands in color on WinEdt, I used highlighting in preference without any result.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Try Options menu -> Maintenance -> Rebuild Default

Answer (score 1):

Possible issue [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277900/highlighting-of-syntax-in-winedt-9?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

On the WinEdt interface:

1. Open the option window.
2. go to option interfaces.
3. In the left part, open: Highlighting: Colors, Keywords,...
4. Right click on Switches and click on Open.
   Then check if you have this
   [image: SWITCHS]

If the commands are still not underlined after reset, I suggest you follow the response given the previous [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277900/highlighting-of-syntax-in-winedt-9?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

"*Add only `BACKGROUND_COLOR="xclEnvBk"` in the section of switches.ini. The rest of the setting from `$$` are for multiline backgrounds. And don't forget to load the script.* "